# css style Centering in safari

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

i'm using css style like this

```
text-align:center;
```

its working in IE and doesn't work with Safari..

any suggestions.

thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you are trying to style.  You are probably trying to center a block level element like a DIV or UL.  In that case, you center using

```
div {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    padding-left:<some fixed size>;
    padding-right:<some fixed size>;
    width:<some fixed size>;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Centering textual content has as far as I know no specific browser/doctype issues. So it look like that you're trying to center something else than text. If you actually want to center a block element, give it a fixed `width` (in pixels) and apply `margin: 0 auto;` on it as well.

Here's an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>SO question 1897444</title>
        <style>
            #center {
                margin: 0 auto; /* top and bottom 0, left and right expanding. */
                width: 300px; /* Required to have a reference point to center. */
                border: 1px solid black; /* Not required, just presentational. */
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="center">Centered block element</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This however won't work in IE in quirks mode. Just ensure that you're using a [**strict** doctype](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/).

Answer (score 1):

[Validating your html and css](http://www.w3.org/QA/Tools/) is the first step to figuring out any rendering issues (even in craptastic browsers like IE 6).

Answer (score 0):

I got the point I made that code:

```
width: 190px;
padding-left:23px;
height: auto;
text-align: left;
line-height: 18px;
```

and its working right now
thanks for all trying to help me